# ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, django

Здравствуйте! Использую `Django` 
есть код -

```
from .models import *
```

При запуске получаю следующее:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "views.py", line 5, in <module>
from .models import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.models'; '__main__' is not a package
```

Пробовал вручную прописать

```
from .models import BotUser, Calculator
```

получаю тот же результат

Comment: Как вы этот код запускаете?

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev `python manage.py migrate`